# calc-button-row is not working as intended

Tags: html, css

I need the buttons to be spaced out. and this is how it looks like. `display: flex; justify-content: space-between; margin: 5% 0;`
is where the problem is. If I remove `display:flex`, it looks jumbled together. But if I put it in, it all gets jubmled horizontally.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    height: 900px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0rem calc((100vw - 1300px) / 2);
  }
  
  .nav-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  
  
  .logo {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 0 2rem;
  }
  
  nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
  }
  
  nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    align-items: center;
    background: #eb92be;
    display: flex;
    font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif;
    font-display: swap;
    height: inherit;
    justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
    color: #232323;
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.30);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.34);
    flex-basis: 400px;
    height: 540px;
    padding: 20px 35px;
}

.calc-button-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 5% 0;
    
}

.calc-button {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
    color: #232323;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 65px;
}

.screen {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.01);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
    color: #232323;
    font-size: 35px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 326px;
}



.calc-button:last-child{
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
    color: #ffff;
    background: #d72880;
}
.calc-button:last-child:hover{
    background-color: inherit;

}

.calc-button:active{
    background-color: #63c9b4;
}

.double{
    flex-basis: 47%;

}
.triple{
    flex-basis: 73%;
}
```

Comment: Post code as a [mcve] and include the HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to space out the .calc-button elements while still maintaining the display: flex property on the .calc-button-row element, you can adjust the flex-basis property of the buttons.

Currently, each button has a flex-basis of 20%, which means that they each take up 20% of the available width in the row. If you want more space between the buttons, you can decrease the flex-basis of each button.

For example, you could set the flex-basis of each button to 15%, which would give each button a bit more space while still keeping them aligned in a row. Alternatively, you could set the flex-basis of the last button to a larger value (e.g. 25%) to give it more space.

Here's an example of how you could adjust the flex-basis of the buttons:

```
.calc-button {
  /* other styles... */
  flex-basis: 15%;
}

.calc-button:last-child {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}`
``
```